# Transform & Overflow in Internet Explorer, blurry text

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transforms

I have a modal that I'm centering via this code

```
.modal {
    max-height: 85%;
    min-width: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 10001;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

Whenever overflow is triggered (via overflow: auto;) The text in internet explorer blurs. It seems to be a conflict with the css for the transform, but I haven't been able to figure out a winning combination. I've tried some suggestions from other issues (using transform3d and adding translate-z). And adding filter: blur(0). So far no luck.